# No keyboard on Raspberry Pi 4 8Gb RAM Ubuntu 64bit

Tags: keyboard, xorg, raspberrypi, 21.04

I recently installed my Ubuntu 64 in my raspberry pi 4 for the second time because I thought I messed up the first time My Logitech USB Unifying wireless keyboard is not working properly, until I realize that some keys are working just entering text in applications is not working.

I was able to install and make update to the system with the Wireless keyboard and mouse connected via Logitech Unifyer USB. But after Rebooting the keyboard does not work properly.

I'm able to enter the password and then once the session is open I can not edit any text, I do can use the `Super` key and enter text in the search bar, also the multimedia buttons work fine, but I can't enter any text on any application like the terminal or the firefox address bar. I can kill x11 to enter a terminal and the keyboard works perfectly.

I'm able to ssh from the laptop to the Pi, but since the keyboard works without x11 I can execute commands directly on the Pi.

New to Raspberry Pi, not sure what to do here.

EDIT:
I moved on to Manjaro and noticed that sometimes the keyboard hangs a bit.

Comment: *which* Raspberry Pi?  There's at least four models.  And for the wireless keyboard is it Bluetooth?  USB?  We need more information on that.

Comment: @ThomasWard Pi 4 with 8Gb RAM

Comment: More info needed about your 'wireless keyboard' too ;)

Comment: Edited, Logitech Unifying receiver via USB, connected on the non USB 3 ports.

Comment: Have you tried enabling X11 instead of Wayland? I think I saw somewhere that this can be the issue.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I didn't do that, instead I installed Manjaro, getting used to Manjaro is going just fine.

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar problem with Ubuntu 21.04 64-bit on a Raspberry Pi 4 B with 4 GB memory, using a Logitech K780 Keyboard on USB, or Logitech K260.  Both keyboards were on a Logitech Unifying Device USB key.

I installed Ubuntu 64 by using rpi-imager in Raspberry Pi OS to write Ubuntu to a 16 GB SD card and then booted from the card.

It is not a keyboard problem because the keys work OK until after I log in,

After I log in, each application window comes up under a clear window that shows the entire application window but prevents any keystroke from falling through to the application window.  Both windows show the 'X" close button but only thee top button works, and it closes both windows.

If, before logging on, I click on he round icon in the lower right corner, and choose "Ubuntu on Xorg" from the resulting menu, I can log on and get a desktop that works normally with the keyboard.

My guess is that the icon in the lower right corner of the login screen selects between two sets of desktop options.  The default set fails and the other set works.